# Reliable SQS Receiver for Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to have a Spark Streaming **SQS Receiver** which deletes SQS messages only **after** they were successfully stored on S3.

For this a **Custom Receiver** can be implemented with the semantics of the **Reliable Receiver**.

The `store(multiple-records)` call [blocks until](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html#receiver-reliability) the given records have been stored and replicated inside Spark.

If the **write-ahead logs** are enabled, all the data received from a receiver gets written [into a write ahead log in the configuration checkpoint directory](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing). The checkpoint directory can be pointed to S3.

After the `store(multiple-records)` blocking call finishes, are the records already stored in the checkpoint directory (and thus can be safely deleted from SQS)?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This is also explained in [this Spark Summit presentation](https://spark-summit.org/2015/events/recipes-for-running-spark-streaming-applications-in-production/).

With **write-ahead logs** and **checkpointing** enabled, the `store(multiple-records)` call blocks until the given records have been written to write-ahead logs.

```
Receiver.store(ArrayBuffer[T], ...)
    ReceiverSupervisorImpl.pushArrayBuffer(ArrayBuffer[T], ...)
    ReceiverSupervisorImpl.pushAndReportBlock(...)
        WriteAheadLogBasedBlockHandler.storeBlock(...)
```

[This implementation](https://www.codatlas.com/github.com/apache/spark/branch-1.4/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/receiver/ReceivedBlockHandler.scala?keyword=WriteAheadLogBasedBlockHandler&line=147) stores the block into the block manager as well as a write ahead log. It does this in parallel, using Scala Futures, and returns only after the block has been stored in both places.